# Python - Import error: No module named cv2

Tags: python, opencv

```
import cv2 as cv

img = cv.imread('Pohotos/cat.jpg')

cv.imshow('Cat', img)

cv.waitKey(0)
```

Currently, I am following a course via Freecodecamp in regards to OpenCV/Python. When I trying to run this script I get an error that there is no module named cv2. Even though I installed everything needed to use OpenCV as shown in the course. Does anyone know how I can fix this?

ps, I use Mac

Comment: Maybe you have installed OpenCV for a different version of python than the one you are using to run the script?

Comment: I used pip install opencv-python again to make sure everything was updated and it seems as it is.

Comment: Maybe `pip` is for a different python than you are using. Are you running the script form the command line or from an IDE?

Comment: I eventually managed to get rid of the error, but now when i am trying to run the script the launcher just freezes.

Comment: Uninstall the current and try this: `pip install opencv-contrib-python==4.1.0.25`

Answer (score 2):

You have probably installed `cv2` in the local folder of somewhere else

You need to find out where that `cv2` module is installed, delete it, and redownload it globally I recommend as a beginner

In the root terminal put `pip3 install opencv-python`

Answer (score 0):

I think you did not install all the packages needed try to install this: pip3 install opencv-python

Comment: Requirement already satisfied: opencv-python in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (4.4.0.46)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.19.3 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from opencv-python) (1.19.4) This is the output i get

Comment: Try maybe reinstalling it using pip3 uninstall opencv-python. And then pip3 install opencv-python

Comment: Maybe do pip3 uninstall opencv-python and then do pip3 install opencv-python

Answer (score 0):

You may not have opencv package. Download opencv and opencv-contrib.
**pip3 install opencv-python opencv-contrib-python**

Comment: This is the output i get:
➜  ~ pip3 install opencv-python
Requirement already satisfied: opencv-python in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (4.4.0.46)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.19.3 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from opencv-python) (1.19.4)
➜  ~ pip3 install opencv-contrib-python
Requirement already satisfied: opencv-contrib-python in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (4.4.0.46)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.19.3 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from opencv-contrib-python) (1.19.4)

Comment: Maybe first do pip3 uninstall opencv-python opencv-contrib-python  and then do pip3 install opencv-python opencv-contrib-python

Comment: Also first check if you have added python3 to your PATH. If not, then add python3 then to your system path then try importing.